# Convert File To Byte-Array, Save In Access-DB, Read From DB And Create File

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

**Hello,** 
 
I am trying to

1. Convert a file to a byte[]
2. Write byte[] in a Access Database
3. Read byte[] from DB
4. Recreate the file from that

1.

```
byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\user\Docs\1.pdf");
```

2.

```
AccessConnector.WriteByteArrayToID(122, bytes);

    public static void WriteByteArrayToID(int aID, byte[] aFile)
    {
        conn.Open();
        dbCommand = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE Belege SET Datei = @file WHERE(ID = @ID)", conn);

        dbCommand.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = aID;
        dbCommand.Parameters.Add("@file", OleDbType.VarBinary).Value = aFile.ToString();

        dbDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(dbCommand);
        dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        conn.Close();
    }
```

3.

```
        DataTable table = AccessConnector.GetFileByteArrayByID(122);
        DataRow row = table.Rows[0];

        System.Text.UTF8Encoding enc = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();

        byte[] newbytes = enc.GetBytes(row.ItemArray[0].ToString());
```

4.

```
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\Users\user\Documents\Docs\a.pdf", newbytes);
```

The thing is, newbytes is way smaller than bytes and the new file isn't accessable. In the Access DB cell are like chinese letters. I already tried to use other encodings. Nothing. Anyone can explain why it's so much smaller (23000 chars to 400 chars). Thanks.

**UPDATE** Added code for the other function

```
    public static DataTable GetFileByteArrayByID(int aID)
    {
        conn.Open();

        dbCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT Datei FROM Belege WHERE (ID = @ID)", conn);

        dbCommand.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = aID;
        dbDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(dbCommand);
        DataTable resultDataTable = new DataTable();
        dbDataAdapter.Fill(resultDataTable);

        conn.Close();
        return resultDataTable;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

```
    public static void WriteByteArrayToID(int aID, byte[] aFile)
    {
        conn.Open();

        dbCommand = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE Belege SET Datei = @file WHERE(ID = @ID)", conn);

        string tmp = Convert.ToBase64String(aFile);

        dbCommand.Parameters.Add("@file", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = tmp;
        dbCommand.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = aID;

        dbDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(dbCommand);
        dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        conn.Close();
    }

    public static DataTable GetFileByteArrayByID(int aID)
    {
        conn.Open();

        dbCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT Datei FROM Belege WHERE (ID = @ID)", conn);

        dbCommand.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = aID;
        dbDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(dbCommand);
        DataTable resultDataTable = new DataTable();
        dbDataAdapter.Fill(resultDataTable);

        conn.Close();
        return resultDataTable;
    } 

        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\user\Music\1.pdf");

        AccessConnector.WriteByteArrayToID(122, bytes);

        DataTable table = AccessConnector.GetFileByteArrayByID(122);

        string file = table.Rows[0][0] as string;

        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\Users\user\Documents\Dokumente\a.pdf", Convert.FromBase64String(file));

        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dbCommand.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = aID;
dbCommand.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.VarBinary).Value = aFile;
```

You're never assigning a value to the `@file` parameter.

Also, there is no need to convert to a string when reading the data, this should work instead:

```
byte[] newbytes = (byte[])table.Rows[0][0];
```

Comment: 1. Yeah, thank you. I didn't saw that... :D 2. He says : can't convert from string to byte[] if I write `byte[] newbytes = (byte[])table.Rows[0][0];`

Comment: In that case, the conversion to string probably already happens in the `GetFileByteArrayByID(...)` method.

Comment: Your code seems fine to _me_, but unfortunately I haven't worked with access databases for ages - what data type is the `Datei` column? It should be something like "BINARY".